# has_many association using foreign_key option seem not to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I'm new to Rails and I'm having an issue with models using "different" primary/foreign key naming conventions than supported by Rails. (OK, I think this MIGHT be the problem)

So these are my 2 models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "PROJECT_ID"
   has_many :employees, :foreign_key => "PROJECT_ID"
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "EMPLOYEE_ID"
   belongs_to :project, :primary_key => "PROJECT_ID"
end
```

And this is what's driving me nuts:

```
> p = Project.find(2)
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."PROJECT_ID" = ? LIMIT 1  [[nil, 2]]
 => #<Project project_id: 2, name: "Project 2", created_at: "2013-08-18 21:26:33.538007", updated_at: "2013-08-18 21:26:33.538007"> 

> p.employees.inspect
  Employee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."PROJECT_ID" = ?  **[[nil, nil]]**
 => "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>"
```

For some reason I don't receive the employees with project_id = 2. It seems that the ? gets substituted with nil.

It works the other way round, check this out

```
> e = Employee.find_by_project_id(2)
  Employee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."project_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 => #<Employee employee_id: 2, first_name: "Will", last_name: "Smith", project_id: 2, created_at: "2013-08-18 21:21:47.884919", updated_at: "2013-08-18 21:22:48.263970"> 

> e.project.inspect
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."PROJECT_ID" = ? ORDER BY "projects"."PROJECT_ID" ASC LIMIT 1  [[nil, 2]]
 => "#<Project project_id: 2, name: \"Project 2\", created_at: \"2013-08-18 21:26:33.538007\", updated_at: \"2013-08-18 21:26:33.538007\">"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "PROJECT_ID"
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project
  self.primary_key = "EMPLOYEE_ID"
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Try to avoid upper case column names at all cost.

for the record here my `schema.rb`

```
  create_table "employees", :primary_key => "EMPLOYEE_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", :primary_key => "PROJECT_ID", :force => true do |t|
  end
```

Comment: Wow, would never have expected to be a uppercase/lowercase issue. thanks, that solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "PROJECT_ID"
   has_many :employees, :foreign_key => "PROJECT_ID", :primary_key => "PROJECT_ID"
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.primary_key = "EMPLOYEE_ID"
   belongs_to :project, :primary_key => "PROJECT_ID", :foreign_key => "PROJECT_ID"
end
```

If you use uppercased field names (i am not sure based on your question) then make sure you always use uppercased names (e.g. find_by_PROJECT_ID). Rails and ActiveRecord are case sensitive.

Comment: I have some experience with databases, there's no such thing as "uppercased field names", so I wasn't aware that this could cause a problem. That hint helped me a lot, thanks.